# Is there a program to execute assembly code and check registers?

Tags: assembly

In our university we have a computer's technology subject in which we have to program in ARM's assembly language.

We have the chance to use a simulator but I was wondering if I was able to execute them in my own Raspberry Pi and to check how the registers are changing. Like on the left of the attached image.

[image: ARMsim].

Comment: I know this is an old post, but which emulator are you using? Do you have the link to ARMSim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do what you want with the debugger gdb.

Compile and link a small test program.

q.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%d\n", i*i);
   return 0;
}
```

gcc -o q q.c

gdb q

Enter the commands

layout asm

layout reg

start

and then si to single step

```
┌──Register group: general─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│rax            0x5555555546b0   93824992233136                                │
│rbx            0x0      0                                                     │
│rcx            0x0      0                                                     │
│rdx            0x7fffffffe1d8   140737488347608                               │
│rsi            0x7fffffffe1c8   140737488347592                               │
│rdi            0x1      1                                                     │
│rbp            0x7fffffffe0e0   0x7fffffffe0e0                                │
│rsp            0x7fffffffe0e0   0x7fffffffe0e0                                │
│r8             0x555555554770   93824992233328                                │
│r9             0x7ffff7de8a50   140737351944784                               │
│r10            0x2      2                                                     │
│r11            0x1      1                                                     │
│r12            0x555555554580   93824992232832                                │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   │0x5555555546b0 <main>           push   %rbp                                │
   │0x5555555546b1 <main+1>         mov    %rsp,%rbp                           │
B+>│0x5555555546b4 <main+4>         sub    $0x20,%rsp                          │
   │0x5555555546b8 <main+8>         mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)                    │
   │0x5555555546bb <main+11>        mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)                    │
   │0x5555555546bf <main+15>        movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)                     │
   │0x5555555546c6 <main+22>        jmp    0x5555555546e6 <main+54>            │
   │0x5555555546c8 <main+24>        mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax                     │
   │0x5555555546cb <main+27>        imul   -0x4(%rbp),%eax                     │
   │0x5555555546cf <main+31>        mov    %eax,%esi                           │
   │0x5555555546d1 <main+33>        lea    0xac(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555554│
   │0x5555555546d8 <main+40>        mov    $0x0,%eax                           │
   │0x5555555546dd <main+45>        callq  0x555555554560 <printf@plt>         │
   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
native process 4701 In: main                           L??   PC: 0x5555555546b4 
(gdb) layout reg
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x6b4
Starting program: /home/common/code/q

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555546b4 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gdb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) to debug assembly code and check the registers. It is available for Raspbian and likely for most other Linux distributions that run on the Pi. It also supports ARM as a target processor.

See also: [ARM assembler in Raspberry Pi](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/09/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-1/)